# How to change status of all test cases in QC test lab

Tags: test-management, quality-center

In QC, How to change status of all test cases(including all steps) together.
I need to make a large set of test cases "pass" in one go, hope there would be some query which can do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe QC does not have any way to update test results of multiple test cases all at once. The fastest way to update multiple tests is the following:

- Just update one test as passed (Make sure you are in grid view)
- Now click on that "passed" cell and it should get highlighted. Now just keep repeating the remaining steps
- copy (cntr +c) duh
- now hit down arrow to go to the next test
- paste

You can actually do this very fast once you start doing it. It is easy to update a 100 tests in 3-4 minutes.
**Important:** Don't wait for QC to update the results in the UI. Just keep typing them on the keyboard and QC UI will keep loading. At intervals it will keep showing lots of tests being updated at once.

Comment: I believe you are correct, there is no easy way to accomplish this.  You can also click in the status field and press 'P' to select passed.  Or you could even write a script to connect to QC and mark each one as passed.

Comment: can anyone explain me with images

Answer (score 3):

One of the good way of use : QC is strong to trace and show what it really append in the project.

If you need to change the status of a lot of test (with step), normally you must execute (like real time) the run of all your test and put the right status (like this you can challenge the real duration of your test) and QC will trace the status of your step.

If you only need to put a "Passed" status for a lot of test, because you know that this part is allready test with success or other reason, you can do a "Fast run" for all the test. To do this, for each test set, in the "Execution grid" :

- select a test  go in the "Tests" menu (between "View" and "Analysis"
  menu)
- select "Replace", a new window is open
- Select the fields that
- you want to change, the actual value and the new value

All step will be on "No run" Status, but it's the truth (you don't execute the test) and it doesn't matter because all reporting will trace the status of your test not the status of the step.

Comment: Thanks OFS.. your said steps works fine and realy helped me a lot doing some other work while the TC's getting passed parallely. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Select all the tests in Grid view and Click RUN.  or Select Test Set(LH side block) and Click Run Test Set (RH side block).
Once after manual run window (new pop up like window opens)
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

This will Pass all test steps of one test case.

One by one all test cases will open in the similar fashion and repeat the above 3 steps.

So far I found this is the easiest way in QC.

If you can code a small snippet in C or C++ to press the shortcut keys, you are done with all test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this for 1000's of steps using the ALM 'Test Factory' & 'Step Factory'

Mark.

Comment: It would help if you could edit your answer to give more information. As it stands ,your answer is likely to be flagged because it does not add much to the existing answers.

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. If you could expand on your answer by describing what you did exactly and how you did it, in a way that helps OP, then it would be a better addition to this 7+ year old question.