# Modifying multiple Test Cases status

Tags: test-management, quality-center

Sometimes I have a list of test cases in the Test Lab and I want to their Status to be changed. Is there any neat way to do it except of just going and doing that one by one?

Comment: Hi Eugene - this one already has an answer here http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/1474/103 , though probably not what you're hoping for (i.e. there isn't a great way of doing it, but there are some good suggestions for easier ways). Long time since I've used QC but I remember that as being one of the big frustrations for me too!

Comment: Thanks for your comments! This is strange that I haven't found the duplicate myself.